# LESS: how to optimize code writing with multiple selectors

Tags: less

I'm using LESS CSS and I have the following situation. Can you suggest me if there is a way to further optimize LESS code?

As you can see, there are many objects sharing properties between them but each one has also its own specific customization.

Thank you

```
footer a
{
  font-weight:bold;

    &#acme, 
    &#email_footer, 
    &#browser_ok, 
    &#browser_old
    {
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
      white-space:nowrap;
      background:url('footer_items.png') no-repeat;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:-9999px;
      border:none;
    }

    &#acme
    {
      width:130px;
      height:25px;
      top:1px;
      background-position:-90px 0;

        &:hover
        {
          background-position:-90px -25px;
        }

        &:active
        {
          top:0px;
        }
    }

    &#email_footer,
    &#browser_ok,
    &#browser_old
    {
      width:38px;
      height:31px;
      top:-3px;
    }


    &#email_footer
    {
      background-position:-230px 0;

        &:hover
        {
          background-position:-230px -31px;
        }

        &:active
        {
          top:-2px;
        }
    }

    &#browser_ok,
    &#browser_old
    {
      background-position:0 -2px;

        &:active
        {
          top:-2px;
        }
    }

    &#browser_ok
    {
      background-position:0 -2px;

        &:hover
        {
          background-position:0 -35px;
        }
    }

    &#browser_old
    {
      background-position:-45px -2px;

        &:hover
        {
          background-position:-45px -35px;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you could still combine some things together. Specifically some of your `:active` code and some of the `background-position` info. In order to keep the newly combined `:active` after `:hover`, I moved the definition containing it below the extra definitions, which should not matter for your code. In all it reduced it by 7 lines of code.

```
footer a
{
  font-weight:bold;

    &#acme, 
    &#email_footer, 
    &#browser_ok, 
    &#browser_old
    {
      display:inline-block;
      position:relative;
      white-space:nowrap;
      background:url('footer_items.png') no-repeat;
      text-align:left;
      text-indent:-9999px;
      border:none;
    }

    &#acme
    {
      width:130px;
      height:25px;
      top:1px;
      background-position:-90px 0;

        &:hover
        {
          background-position:-90px -25px;
        }

        &:active
        {
          top:0px;
        }
    }

    &#email_footer
    {
      background-position:-230px 0;

        &:hover
        {
          background-position:-230px -31px;
        }

    }

    &#browser_ok,
    &#browser_old
    {
      background-position:0 -2px;   
    }

    &#browser_ok
    {   
        &:hover
        {
          background-position:0 -35px;
        }
    }

    &#browser_old
    {
      background-position:-45px -2px;

        &:hover
        {
          background-position:-45px -35px;
        }
    }

    &#email_footer,
    &#browser_ok,
    &#browser_old
    {
      width:38px;
      height:31px;
      top:-3px;

        &:active
        {
          top:-2px;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok... thank you, advantages are clearly present but less than I could expect.... I hoped that could be some "trick" like nested rules and '&' operator to write a multiple selector definition (for example for &#email_footer,&#browser_ok,&#browser_old) and inside it, specify some additional and specialized rules but maybe.... it's not possible....